# continuation passing style vs monads

Tags: functional-programming, monads, continuation-passing

What are the differences between continuation passing style (cps) and monads.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As mentioned in [The essence of functional programming](http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~david/cs442/monads.pdf):

> Programming with monads strongly reminiscent of continuation—passing style (CPS), and this paper explores the relationship between the two. In a sense they are equivalent: CPS arises as a special case of a monad, and any monad may be embedded in CPS by changing the answer type. But the monadic approach provides additional insight and allows a finer degree of control.

That paper is quite rigorous, and actually it doesn't quite expand on the relationship between CPS and monads. Here I attempt to give an informal, but illustrative example:

(Note: Below is an understand of Monad from a newbie (myself), though after writing it it does appear to look like one of those high-rep users' answer. Please do take it with a ton of salt)

Consider the classic `Maybe` monad

```
-- I don't use the do notation to make it 
-- look similar to foo below

bar :: Maybe Int
bar =
    Just 5 >>= \x ->
    Just 4 >>= \y ->
    return $ x + y

bar' :: Maybe Int
bar' =
    Just 5 >>= \x ->
    Nothing >>= \_ ->
    return $ x

GHCi> bar
Just 9
GHCi> bar'
Nothing
```

So the computation stops as soon as `Nothing` is encountered, nothing new here. Let's try to mimic such a monadic behavior using CPS:

Here is our vanilla `add` function using CPS. We are using all `Int` here instead of algebric data type to make it easier:

```
add :: Int -> Int -> (Int -> Int) -> Int
add x y k = k (x+y)

GHCi> add 3 4 id
7
```

Notice how similar it is to a monad

```
foo :: Int
foo =
    add 1 2 $ \x -> -- 3
    add x 4 $ \y -> -- 7
    add y 5 $ \z -> -- 12
    z

GHCi> foo
12
```

OK. Suppose that we want the computation to be capped at 10. That is, whatever computation must stop when the next step would result in a value larger than 10. This is sort of like saying "a Maybe computation must stop and return `Nothing` as soon as any value in the chain is `Nothing`). Let's see how we can do it by writing a "CPS transformer"

```
cap10 :: (Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int)
cap10 k = \x ->
    if x <= 10 
    then 
        let x' = k x in 
        if x' <= 10 then x' else x
    else x

foo' :: Int
foo' =
    add 1 2 $ cap10 $ \x -> -- 3
    add x 4 $ cap10 $ \y -> -- 7
    add y 5 $ cap10 $ \z -> -- 12
    undefined

GHCi> foo'
7
```

Notice that the final return value can be `undefined`, but that is fine, because the evaluation stops at the 3rd step (`z`).

We can see that `cap10` "wraps" the normal continuation with some extra logic. And that's very close to what monad to -- glue computations together with some extra logic.

Let's go one step further:

```
(>>==) :: ((Int -> Int) -> Int) -> (Int -> Int) -> Int
m >>== k = m $ cap10 k

foo'' :: Int
foo'' =
    add 1 2 >>== \x -> -- 3
    add x 4 >>== \y -> -- 7
    add y 5 >>== \z -> -- 12
    undefined

GCHi> foo''
7
```

Woa! Maybe we have just invented the `Cap10` monad!

Now if we look at the [source code of Cont](https://google.com/codesearch#A3NG3tctuIg/core/libraries/mtl/Control/Monad/Cont.hs&q=package%3aghc%20Cont), we see that `Cont` is

```
newtype Cont r a = Cont { runCont :: (a -> r) -> r }
```

The type of `runCont` is

```
Cont r a -> (a -> r) -> r
((a -> r) -> r) -> (a -> r) -> r
```

Which lines up nicely with the type of our `>>==`

### Now to actually answer the question

Now after typing all this I reread the original question. The OP asked for the "difference" :P

I guess the difference is CPS gives the caller more control, where as usually the `>>=` in a monad is fully controlled by the monad's author.

Answer (score 9):

You might want to have a look at this http://blog.sigfpe.com/2008/12/mother-of-all-monads.html

Answer (score 5):

An interesting paper which explores the issue is ["Imperative functional programming"](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/imperative.ps.Z), by Peyton Jones and Wadler.

It's the paper which introduced monadic IO, and it has comparisons to alternative approaches, including CPS.

The authors conclude:

> So monads are more powerful than continuations, but only because of the types! It is not clear whether this is only an artifact of the Hindley-Milner type system, or whether the types are revealing a difference of fundamental importance (our own intuition it's the latter -- but it's only an intuition.)

Comment: That _powerful_ is not well-defined (like [this](https://ftp.cs.wpi.edu/pub/techreports/pdf/08-01.pdf)). If all interested is the expressiveness, it is not hard to conclude, just because monads expose "(quite)" more language structure (thus do more things) than continuations in the paper. The more significant artifact actually comes from the meta level: if the language is not lazy-by-default, there are not many reasons to show the power of the monadic approach, because there are many other styles not ruled out by the evaluation rules making the infrastructure equi-powerful, far easily.

Answer (score -12):

There is no relation, thus the question makes about as much sense as asking about the difference between the color blue and Pluto.

Comment: Lol well I was thinking monad implementation take create and return monads.

Comment: I downvoted, because there is strong relation (see sigfpe's post below): continuations form a monad, and every monad can be represented using continuation monad: monadic bind type can be written `m a -> Cont (m b) a`.

Comment: I also down-voted. CPS and Monad are very much related. In fact, I suspect that is why most bind definitions are `m >>= k` as in "`k` for continuation"